# Out of memory exception on deserializing IPAddress

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

When I try to deserialize from MyConfig.xml I get an out of memory exception at

```
System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(String ipString)
MyNamespace.IPRange.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
```

**IPRange.cs**

```
public class IPRange : IXmlSerializable
{
    public IPRange () { }

    public IPAddress StartIP { get; set; }
    public IPAddress EndIP { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        this.StartIP = IPAddress.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("StartIP"));
        this.EndIP = IPAddress.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("EndIP"));
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("StartIP", this.StartIP.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("EndIP", this.EndIP.ToString());
    }
}
```

**MyConfig.cs**

```
public class MyConfig
{
    [XmlArrayItem("IPRange")]
    public List<IPRange> DMZ { get; set; }
}
```

**MyConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyConfig>
    <DMZ>
        <IPRange StartIP="{some start ip}" EndIP="{some end ip}" />
        <IPRange StartIP="{some start ip}" EndIP="{some end ip}" />
    </DMZ>
</MyConfig>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Please help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds interesting. Have you tried debugging? Do `reader.GetAttribute("StartIP")` and `reader.GetAttribute("StartIP")` return reasonable values? Have you tried it multiple times and seen the error at the same point in your code each time? If you break before the offending call, what's your memory usage look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by writing *reader.Read()* at the end of the function...

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    this.StartIP = IPAddress.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("StartIP"));
    this.EndIP = IPAddress.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("EndIP"));

    reader.Read();
}
```